# How to fill database with XML file using Grails

Tags: xml, grails, groovy

I'm playing around with Grails and now wonder how to fill my database with a local XML file on a computer. I've tried this in BootStrap class

```
class BootStrap {
    def init = { servletContext ->
        def users= new XmlSlurper().parse(new File("C:\\Users\\users.xml"))
        users.user.each()
                {
                    p -> new user(userid: p.@userid, name: p.@username, email: p.@email,)
                }
    }
    def destroy = {

    }
}
```

But I get an error that says:

> [Fatal Error] users.xml:2:10: DOCTYPE is disallowed when the
>   feature "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" set to
>   true.

How to resolve it?

Comment: Unless this is a copy and paste error: you should use uppercase classnames (e.g. `User` not `user`) -- this can even lead to parse errors in groovy (not this one). Why is this error about `products.xml`? If you are rewriting your problem to a "minimal failing case", please make sure, that the error messages etc match.

Comment: Aww, it must be users.xml

Comment: What java and grails version is this?

Answer (score 1):

Your XML has a doctype which the slurper doesn't like, you can either remove it from the XML doc or to disable the check create your slurper like this:

```
XmlSlurper xmlSlurper = new XmlSlurper()
xmlSlurper.setFeature( "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", false )
xmlSlurper.setFeature( "http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false )
xmlSlurper.parse(...
```

Once you've got over this hurdle you may hit others such as your definition of user is lowercase and you have a trailing comma in the constructor.